# Adding foreign Key in table is taking too long

Tags: mysql, sql, database, data-science

I have two tables (using mysql) : ***tactic_themes(code_tac,code_th)*** and ***tactics(code_tac,tactic_data)*** which tactic_themes contains 13 million rows and tactics 3 million rows but running query that makes "code_tac" column a foreign key takes too long, i mean more than 2 hours!

**The query SQL** :

```
ALTER TABLE tactic_themes
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_foreign_key_name
FOREIGN KEY (code_tac)
REFERENCES tactics(code_tac);
```

**My mysql server variables** :

| Variable_name | Value |
| --- | --- |
| aria_pagecache_buffer_size | 134217728 |
| aria_sort_buffer_size | 268434432 |
| bulk_insert_buffer_size | 8388608 |
| innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size | 16777216 |
| innodb_buffer_pool_dump_at_shutdown | ON |
| innodb_buffer_pool_dump_now | OFF |
| innodb_buffer_pool_dump_pct | 25 |
| innodb_buffer_pool_filename | ib_buffer_pool |
| innodb_buffer_pool_instances | 1 |
| innodb_buffer_pool_load_abort | OFF |
| innodb_buffer_pool_load_at_startup | ON |
| innodb_buffer_pool_load_now | OFF |
| innodb_buffer_pool_size | 16777216 |
| innodb_change_buffer_max_size | 25 |
| innodb_change_buffering | all |
| innodb_log_buffer_size | 8388608 |
| innodb_sort_buffer_size | 1048576 |
| join_buffer_size | 262144 |
| join_buffer_space_limit | 2097152 |
| key_buffer_size | 16777216 |
| mrr_buffer_size | 262144 |
| myisam_sort_buffer_size | 8388608 |
| net_buffer_length | 8192 |
| preload_buffer_size | 10485760 |
| read_buffer_size | 262144 |
| read_rnd_buffer_size | 524288 |
| sort_buffer_size | 524288 |
| sql_buffer_result | OFF |

Can someone help?

Comment: If code_tac is the PK for both tables (which is what it looks like) then is there a reason why you split this data into two tables rather than holding the data in a single table?

Comment: is `code_tac` the primary key of `tactics`?

Comment: @NickW yes because a tactic can have an undetermined amount of themes

Comment: @TheImpaler yes

Comment: If you have config variables for `aria_*`, I think you are using MariaDB, not MySQL. Please run `SELECT @@version;` to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

> i mean more than 2 hours!

Without knowing exactly what the hardware is and spending some time analyzing your environment, we can't comment on whether that is in any way abnormal. And even if it were that would make your question off topic on stack overflow - which is about writing code, not fixing hardware/services.

When working with large datasets, some things will take a lot of time. People have been pre-empting this for decades by *only running the slow things once*. Don't keep recreating your dataset - find a way of updating / adding to the data you already have.

And there's also a way of running slow things to reduce the impact on the service - there's a nice packaged solution [in the Percona Toolkit](https://docs.percona.com/percona-toolkit/pt-online-schema-change.html).